# SQL WHERE clause that must be written in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Could someone show me the correct way to write the following clause in Access?

```
WHERE (
    (([Production Table].[Production Date]) >=#7/1/2018#) 
    and ([Production Table].[Production Date]) < #" + yesterday + "#) 
    and [JITL NUMBER] = 60
```

Comment: What gives you the impression that it's incorrect as written?

Comment: I was receiving an error message whenever I executed as written above.  The  '+' should have been an ampersand '&'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to be dynamic subtract 1 from Date(). Also, I had to use between to get the date range to work.

```
WHERE ((([Production Table].[Production Date]) 
Between #7/1/2018# And (Date()-1)) AND (([Production Table].JITL_NUMBER)=60))
```

Comment: This also worked.  Thank you for simplifying!  I'm going to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have the full picture but in access you concatenate with & (Ampersand)

```
WHERE (
    (([Production Table].[Production Date]) >=#7/1/2018#) 
    and ([Production Table].[Production Date]) < #" & yesterday & "#) 
    and [JITL NUMBER] = 60
```